# How do I set encoding in an NpgsqlConnection

Tags: c#, postgresql, encoding, npgsql

I have a PostgreSQL database, which uses character encoding `WIN1252`.

When querying the database, some records will produce an error when trying to read the data, because it is trying to convert it to `UTF8`. This happens on some foreign names containing certain non-Latin characters.

The error is:

```
ERROR: 22P05: character with byte sequence 0x81 in encoding "WIN1252" has no equivalent in encoding "UTF8"
```

It happens when I call `Read()` on the `NpgsqlDataReader`.

My connection is defined as:

```
new NpgsqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=xyz;User Id=****;Password=****;");
```

What can I do to read this data using C#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've managed to solve the problem. There is no way of setting the property in the connection string or any of the properties of the `NpgsqlConnection` or `NpgsqlCommand`.

However, I was able to set the value of `client_encoding` in a query. So directly after opening the connection I first executed the (non)query:

```
set client_encoding = 'WIN1252'
```

After that, any subsequent command on the same connection used the proper encoding and returned the results without complaints.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to change the connection string but i had no luck with that.
The problem got solved by chaning the database settings file and reload it.

So i started pgadmin and executed

```
SHOW config_file;
```

which gave me

```
 C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/14/data/postgresql.conf
```

in this file i changed the **lc_messages** from **lang_language.1252 to UTF8**.
After that i reloaded this config in pg admin by right click on the server name and press "Reload Configuration".

All settings are now set to UTF8 and it just worked fine.

```
lc_messages = 'UTF8'            # locale for system error message
                    # strings
lc_monetary = 'UTF8'            # locale for monetary formatting
lc_numeric = 'UTF8'         # locale for number formatting
lc_time = 'UTF8'                # locale for time formatting
...
```