# Error saving special char with postgresql and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, postgresql

I'm writing a WPF application to migrate some data from SQLServer to postgresql.

My setup is:

- Entity Framework 6
- npgsql 2.2.5
- Npgsql.EntityFramework.2.2.5
- PostGree 9.3

I'm having trouble to save a special character. This only happens with special chars. If I navigate through exception's stack I can catch a SQL statement that if I run it directly on database it works.

```
if (person.Something == true)
    newPerson.Something = "SIM";
else
    newPerson.Something = "NÃO";

this.context.Persons.Add(newPerson);
this.context.SaveChanges();
```

The inner exception(translated) is that:

> InnerException = {"ERROR: 22001: value � too large for
>   character(3)"}

I assume the problem is with encoding. I cannot change postgre database encoding because an old system uses it. This is the database setup:

[image]

I tried to change the enconding on the connection string with "Encoding = UNICODE", "Encoding = UTF8" and others, but nothing worked.

Comment: what if you change the length of the Column in the database to be VarChar(10) for example perhaps the error is telling you that you are trying to update a field with char length greater than 3

Comment: the column size is 3, although there's already the "NÃO" string stored in this column.

Comment: exactly and the error is telling you what the problem is.. make the column size bigger and then test it..

Comment: I edited the comment, I pressed enter accidentally. As I said, if I insert "NÃO" directly with a SQL statement it works and I cannot change this database.

Comment: what does the structure of newPerson look like also try to do the trim of the string.. to test the length to make sure it's 3 do something like this 
`var nameLength = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("NÃO");` or replace it like this 
`var nameLength = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(newPerson.Something);` I would expect 3 in both cases..

Comment: maybe http://stackoverflow.com/a/16354337/225389 and Inquery modifying Interceptor (like http://www.entityframework.info/Home/FullTextSearch) can help